# breaking a hash and understanding it

Tags: security, encryption, hashcode

I have a hash value taken from a database. This is a php-mysql based application. The assignment given to me is to break it and tell what it would be in plain text.
To me it seems as a SHA-512. This is because of the following output taken from a function in my test application:

```
echo 'SHA-512:      ' . crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$')
```

Now I need some help in understanding how to break it. I have tried online crackers, and searched some rainbow tables as well, but of no use. I need a guide line or a method from the security experts present over here to sort it out for me.

Comment: You will not be able to "break" SHA-512. The chance of finding a collision is approximately 1.34*10^154.

Comment: +1 because I don't think this question deserves down votes. The request is clear. It's not a bad question because the answer is that it's not currently possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptographic hashes are designed to be non-reversible. So you can't do it, other than by brute force (i.e., trying every possible string to see if it hashes to the same value). For SHA-512 (which is SHA-2 in 512 bits), that is computationally infeasible.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function or similar, and you'll get more background on how this is supposed to work.